# Does the android camera guide get the activity life cycle wrong?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-lifecycle, onpause

In the Android documentation on creating a custom camera `Activity` (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera) they get an instance of the `Camera` in `onCreate()` and release it in `onPause()`.

Is this correct? Isn't it possible for the `Activity` to skip `onCreate()` and spin back up from the `onResume()` event after a pause? i.e. shouldn't I be getting my reference to the `Camera` in `onResume()` as well and have some sort of `setCamera()` method in the `CameraPreview`/`SurfaceView` class?

I'm just getting started with Android development, so maybe I'm missing something here... but the life cycle I'm looking at is located here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this correct?

It does not look correct.

> shouldn't I be getting my reference to the Camera in onResume() as well

I would skip the "as well" part and simply obtain the `Camera` instance in `onResume()`.

IOW, you want parallelism:

- If you clean it up in `onPause()`, set it up in `onResume()`
- If you clean it up on `onStop()`, set it up in `onStart()` (or possibly the combination of `onCreate()` and `onRestart()`
- If you clean it up in `onDestroy()`, set it up in `onCreate()`

In the case of a `Camera`, you do not want to hold onto it when you are not in the foreground, as other apps cannot access it while you have it, so I would go for the `onResume()`/`onPause()` pairing.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare, just a real quick follow-up question regarding the Activity and View life-cycle. Is CameraPreview.surfaceCreated(holder) always called after Activity.onResume() - ie. if I set the camera in onResume() will it be ready to begin capturing in surfaceCreated()?... from some simple debug statements this seems to be the case. Or would you recommend adding/removing the CameraPreview to the FrameHolder in the onResume()/onPause() events (I assume this would make for a sluggish transition though..)

Comment: @Cailen: "always" is a strong term. :-) That being said, AFAIK, `surfaceCreated()` will be called after `onResume()`.